# AsposeOCR API implementation Runtime Error

Tags: java

pls I'm trying to use AsposeOCR API to read text from images into excel file, but after installations and setups , at runtime I run into this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError , caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy...

My code:

public static void read(){

```
  AsposeOCR api = new AsposeOCR();
  File imgfile = showDialog();
  RecognitionSettings setts = new RecognitionSettings();
  RecognitionResult rs = api.RecognitionPage(imgfile.getAbspath(), setts);
  rs.save("excel.xlsx", Format.Xlsx);
```

}

The error occurred at line 4.
Pls help me out, I don't know what else to do...
Thanks...

Comment: Hello all, is anyone there to help?

Comment: Hello oooooo plssssssss